# Persistent TCP connection with ARM

Tags: java, tcp

I am trying to write a simple TCP server, but the problem I have is that the socket gets closed after the first run (it's running in a thread, by the way). I could try rewriting it without ARM (Automatic Resource Management), that bock in round squares after `try` - but I would rather keep it.

So, it there a way to write a simple persistent TCP server by using ARM in Java?

```
public class Server {
/* Server */

public int port = 8088;

public Server (int port){
    this.port = port;
    System.out.println("Will listen on port " + this.port);
}

public Server () {
    System.out.println("Will listen on default port " + port);
}

public void start() {

    try (ServerSocket initSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
         Socket socket = initSocket.accept();
         BufferedReader bfin = 
                 new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
         BufferedOutputStream bfout =
                 new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())  
         )
    {
        String line = bfin.readLine();
        while (line != null && !"BYE\n".equals(line)){
            String answer = parseadd(line) + "\n";
            System.out.println("From client: " + line);
            bfout.write(answer.getBytes());
            bfout.write("BYE\n".getBytes());
            bfout.flush();
            line = bfin.readLine(); 
        }
        System.out.println("Exiting server while loop!");
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception caught when trying to");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}


}
```

Comment: You need a loop calling `accept()`, and to start a thread to manage and close each accepted socket, and not test it as a try-with-resources resource. See the Java Custom Networking tutorial.

Comment: So, I can't really make this using ARM?